# maven conditional dependencies

Tags: maven-2, alfresco, jackrabbit

We would like to bundle library dependencies from (Alfresco or Jackrabbit or ...) based on the  customer choice. The number of dependencies actually varies based on the chosen vendor. How do  we provide hooks at the maven level, so that the final product just includes the dependent jars as per customer selection.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could achieve this by putting the needed dependencies into vendor-specific [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) in your pom:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>Alfresco</id>
        <dependencies>
            ...
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>Jackrabbit</id>
        <dependencies>
            ...
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then you can activate the desired profile for your build like:

```
mvn -PJackrabbit install
```