# Javascript Validation in Java 15+ JUnit Test

Tags: java, nashorn, java-15

Now that Nashorn has been deprecated & removed in [JDK 15](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/372) what is the best approach to validate that a String is valid Javascript in a JUnit test?

Previous Code:

```
    private void validateJavascript(final String js) throws ScriptException {
        final NashornScriptEngine scriptEngine = (NashornScriptEngine) new NashornScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine();
        final CompiledScript compile = scriptEngine.compile(js);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @tgdavies just found that thread as well and managed to solve this by adding that standalone implementation.

Comment: I found that via your answer, but I think closing as duplicate is more helpful to SO generally.

Answer (score 1):

Found the following similar thread [Different Nashorn engine for Java < 15 and >= 15?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66061017/different-nashorn-engine-for-java-15-and-15) which pointed me to standalone implementation which can be added as a test dependency:

```
testImplementation 'org.openjdk.nashorn:nashorn-core:15.2'
```

And then instantiated as follows:

```
final NashornScriptEngine scriptEngine = (NashornScriptEngine) new NashornScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine();
```