# does maven support customize packaging?

Tags: maven

I want to include `jointcorp-instruction.jar` only when `jointcorp.enabled=true`, does maven support this or any plugin support this?

[image]

Comment: Additional possible duplicates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636595/maven-exclude-dependency-with-condition), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408696/maven-conditional-dependencies), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166895/different-dependencies-for-different-build-profiles).